# Compiling with a circular dependency between methods

Tags: objective-c, circular-dependency

I have two classes. Let's call them `Dog` and `Cat`.

In `Dog` I have an *instance* of `Cat`, and `Dog` has a method, `harrassCat`. Inside `harrassCat`, I invoke a `Cat` method, `swipeAtDogsNose:`, which uses properties of `Dog` to calculate its output.

The problem is in the header files.  I import `Cat`'s header file into `Dog` and create a property. I then access this property in `harrassCat`.

For now, I have an `NSArray` with all the required properties passed as arguments in `swipeAtDogsNose:`. I want to directly access the properties of `Dog` within `swipeAtDogsNose:`, but I cannot import the `Dog` header into the `Cat` header because it causes a circular dependency and it fails to compile.

I read on Stack Overflow that when you have circular dependency, you can use `@class` to access another class. How do I import `Dog` using `@class` so that the method declaration in Cat.h looks something like this:

```
- (BOOL)swipeAtDogsNose:(Dog *)theDog;
```

Comment: @JoshCaswell Nice edits :)

Comment: Glad you like it. I always find `A` and `B` or `1` and `2` hard to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is called [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) and declare it by just adding the declaration before the interface of the other class in the header file.

```
@class ClassB;

@interface ClassA
...
```

Mind that you don't need to do it, you need it just if any method signature requires a type which is not defined and cannot be imported in the header file, if you have a `@property` of that type or if you have class member of that type.

Basically: if the type name appears in the header then you need to forward declare it (or `#import` the header), otherwise you can just `#import` inside `.m` file. You don't have to import the header inside the other header, importing inside the implementation file is enough.

Answer (score 0):

ClassA:

```
@class ClassB;

@interface classA

@property (strong, nonatomic) classB* propertyThatUseClassB

@end
```

ClassB:

```
@class ClassA;

@interface classB

@property (strong, nonatomic) classA* propertyThatUseClassA

@end
```

Comment: And import you `.h` files in your `.m` and you're all set